# How can I group random files (with different names) into appropriate folders without using an LLM?

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, nlp

I want to build a product that organises folders/subfolders and files automatically based on their files names and clustering them into groups based on similarity of file names. I know this can be tackled with an LLM, specifically ChatGPT4 but this presents a few issues. 1. Privacy, not everyone will want to send their file names to this system. 2. Input length, the OpenAI context window is limited to a certain length so if you had a folder with 1000 files or more it will not be able to process this. 3. Token cost, even if you could process 1000 files or more this would start getting very expensive. For this reason I am looking for an alternative. (A local LLM could solve the privacy concerns but wouldn't address problem 2).

I am sure there are machine learning techniques that exist that can cluster words together based on the similarity of the meaning behind the words but I haven't been able to find a library that does what I need out of the box.

Here is an example of what I want to achieve:

Input (file names):

- historyHomework.pdf
- reports.docx
- mountains.png
- historyTest.docx
- weatherdata.csv
- geographynotes.docx
- artwork1.png
- artwork2.png

Output (proposed folder names):

- History
- Geography
- Art
- Other

Note that the output folders are not pre-determined groups. For instance the input could be 10 other random files, and the algorithm you should suggest new names based on the inputs.

The closest solution I came to was using WordNet in python and finding hypernyms to group words. The problem is it wasn't very accurate.

Comment: And how about using a words-to-vectors algorithm such as Word2Vec? The more advanced option is to download an actual LLM to your local machine. There are tools such as LM Studio that allow you to do that. Then you can just ask the LLM to create the groups for you.